# Should child component have states? - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

Suppose, we have the parent component `App`, and it has a child component `Search`.

For this example:

The `Search` component displays the text typed in its input field, via `setState`, i.e:

```
const Search = () => {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = React.useState("");
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="search">Search: </label>
      <input id="search" type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
      <p>
        Searching for <strong>{searchTerm}</strong>.
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Method 1: let the child component `Search` have its own state.

Should the `Search` component have its own state, i.e use `UseState()`? Or is this a bad practice?

Method 2: let the parent component `App` manage the child's state.

Should the value from the `Search` component be passed up to the parent component `App` and then let the `App` component manage the state via `setState()`, then pass the updated value back down to the search component?

Which method is a better practice?

Edit:

I don't know why this question is flagged as opinion based. I understand there will some disagreement, but that is bound to happen when a question revolves around using the correct design pattern.
If you disagree, then why not flag all the stack overflow questions that revolves around which design pattern to use, or the "correct SQL database/table to use" as opinion based as well.

Comment: I think that Search component should have own state. It solution incapsulate logic inside one component. It will be implements principe of simple responsibility

Comment: Global / scope based state is something vanilla React does not do well.  The reason for the multitude of state managers for react.  Redux etc.  Recoil is a very react type state manager you might want to try   https://recoiljs.org/  I believe  it's developed by the react team.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, the state should be as far down the hierarchy as possible. The main reason to lift the state further up is if you need to access the state from multiple components.

Then you can lift it to the parent, and pass it to multiple children. If the state need to be accessed in many places, you can use a context or some other state managing library.

Answer (score 1):

If you need value of search anywhere else in your project then it's better to manage states centrally(if project is small) or use `useContext` hook. Else if value will only be needed by `Search` component then it's better that state is managed in component itself.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what do you need for your project? In fact, you are acting on this question.
if parent component will use state in app.js, you should  pass state to parent component. but iif not needed, you should setState in child component.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to find an answer to this question is to think contextually.

### The search a self contained component with no impact outside of its own context

Then you should keep the state closer to where it will be manipulated : inside the component.

### Is it part of a whole and is a system that reaches the parent or even components outside of tree ?

In this case you should rely on the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or use a state management library like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) that will avoid performance pitfall in some complex cases. Having your state managed by the Root component makes it available to your whole App and prevents you from doing painful [prop drilling](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/prop-drilling).